# $A_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_6$

Tags: group-isomorphism

How do i show that $D_6$ has an element of order 6 but $A_4$ has only elements of order 3 and 2 and thus,  $A_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_6$? Can someone explain to me? Thanks!

Comment: $D_6$ is the group of symmetries of the hexagon? That is, has order $12$?

Comment: yes $D_6$ and $A_4$ both have order 12

Answer (score 1):

$D_6$ is the group of symmetries of the hexagon.
The $60$-degree rotation is in $D_6$ and has order $6$.

However, [no element of $S_4$ has order $6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592629/how-to-show-the-symmetric-group-s-4-has-no-elements-of-order-6). See also [Element structure of symmetric group:S4](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_symmetric_group:S4).